# Find Input type = button in a div and click twice using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to find input type =  button in a `<div>` and click twice using jquery

I tried this

```
$('#'+exact).find('input[type="button"]').click();
```

but not working.

Comment: How do we know what is `exact`, what is your HTML structure, how the event handler is binded..? Please go through [ask]

Comment: Exact is div id.All i have to do is find the button in div and click twice.

Comment: Yes, that I understood. If you *copy paste* the line of code one more time, it should trigger click two times. If it is not working, then how do we know why it is not working..? For finding the issue, we need to see all that.

Comment: Thanks T J for help.Its done .

This is the answer $('#'+exact).find('[type="button"]').click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [`:button`](http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/) selector to find the button (*equivalent to using `$("button, input[type='button']" )`*), and cache the reference to it in a variable to avoid querying the `DOM` two times.

```
var $button = $('#'+exact).find(':button').click();
$button.click();
```

or

```
var $button = $('#'+exact).find(':button').trigger("click");
$button.trigger("click");
```